# Netty: Does the I/O thread responsible for the channel invoke ChannelFutureListener synchronously after the future completes

Tags: netty

Looking at javadoc for https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelFuture.html for the addListener method:

```
ChannelFuture addListener(GenericFutureListener<? extends Future<? super java.lang.Void>> listener)
Description copied from interface: Future
Adds the specified listener to this future. The specified listener is notified when this future is done. If this future is already completed, the specified listener is notified immediately.
```

Wondering what is the guarantee about when the listeners are invoked? Is it invoked by the I/O thread and whether it is done synchronously after the event completes, e.g. if I have used it for writeAndFlush(...).addListener(...) is the listener invoked synchronously after the write is flushed?

Also, is it okay to schedule a runnable on the eventloop from the ChannelFutureListener, which I suppose also runs on the I/O thread and therefore is guaranteed to be called after the listener call exits ?